# Firebase: Create a named child reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've made a react component which logs each time my cat has been fed. However at the moment it doesn't automatically create a new empty log for each day. I'm trying to add a method to create a new entry at midnight each day but in order for it to work with the existing component i've made, each new entry needs to be named in the 'DD-MM-YYYY' format. Whilst I can rework the component to not use that, it's handy at a glance when I go into firebase to see the dates a log has been created and would prefer not to change it.

So here is my problem: Whenever I try to do the following, firebase ignores my date format and puts a random key in instead:

```
this.midnightCheck = () => {
   // If it is midnight, update the state
   if(moment().format('HH:mm') === '00:00') {
     this.dbroot.push(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')).child('date').set(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
   }
}
```

I've also tried this.dbroot.set() but that doesn't work as it requires the childref to exist first.

Update: I have just tried the following which technically worked but it also overwrote the entire ref instead of just adding a new date to the ref.

```
this.midnightCheck = () => {
  // If it is midnight, update the state
  if(moment().format('HH:mm') === '18:34') {
    console.info('midnightCheck is updating the state')
    this.dbroot.child(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')).set({
      date : moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
      logs : {}
    })
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `push()`, Firebase writes the data to a new location with an auto-generated push ID.

If you want to determine the name of a new child yourself, call `child()`:

```
var date = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
this.dbroot.child(date).child('date').set(date)
```

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I've just tried that but it's not adding a new child node, it's overwriting all of them and replacing it with just the new one!

Comment: It's working now for some reason. Must have been a glitch. Thanks man!